# Resize column functionality required in Google Sites List Page Template

Tags: google-sites

I need a resize column capability in on a Google Sites Page based on the List Page Template. 
Can anyone suggest a possible workaround for this, other than embedding a spreadsheet which looks really bad

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to change columns size. About Google Spreadsheets, they look better if you insert the URL of a published spreadsheet (published as web page that is). The embed tag looks sth like this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQLcI0Y7X4oaW8eBYkt5r4.../pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
```